# How can i use Form Api in a custom block?

Tags: 8, forms, blocks

I’ve created a custom module and it works fine. I use the Form Api to display form and it is also working fine.

For now, i can access my module with the route that i defined in `xxx.routing.yml`

Now, for templating reasons, i would like to create a block.

I’ve followed this tutorial :

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block

I’ve added my block and i can see it in font end.

My question is how tu reuse my previous class in `src/Form/WebservicesBulletinForm.php` :

```
class WebservicesBulletinForm extends FormBase {
    // code based on Api form
}
```

now i have in `src/Plugin/Block/WebservicesBulletinBlock.php`

```
class WebservicesBulletinBlock extends BlockBase {
    // code based on  APi form
}
```

I can see my block in front, i see my forms but i have some issues due to the fact that i extand `BlockBase` and not `FormBase`.

How can i use Form Api in a custom block ?

I’ve look in the module folder to see other example but did’t manage to clearly understand.

For now, if i do this :

```
class WebservicesBulletinBlock extends BlockBase {

    public function build() {
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\webservices_bulletin\Form\WebservicesBulletinForm');
    return $form;
   }

}
```

I can see the form but it doesn't work. Should i insert all the form process code in WebservicesBulletinBlock ?

I need a simple example in order to adapt my code.

Comment: This should work, see for example the core search block http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/search/src/Plugin/Block/SearchBlock.php

Comment: @4k4 you’re right, `$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm()` works. I’ve tested it with other custom blocks and it’s ok. My form in my custom block which has an issue allow user to download a file after the form is submitted. Maybe the issue is related to this (the form is validated but there is no file downloaded and it works if i access directly with the route. I need to investigate more on this.